# Cumulative count over weeks in SQL

Tags: sql, count, cumulative-sum

I have table of items with owner ids referencing to a user from users table.

I want to show for each week (group by week) how many items were created that week per user + all the items created before - cumulative count.

For this table:

| id | owner | created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxxxx | '2021-01-01' |
| 2 | xxxxx | '2021-01-01' |
| 3 | xxxxx | '2021-01-09' |

I want to get:

| count | owner | week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | xxxxx | '2021-01-01' - '2021-01-07' |
| 3 | xxxxx | '2021-01-08' - '2021-01-14' |

This is code for non-cumulative count. How can I change it to be cumulative?

```
select
    count(*),
    uu.id,
    date_trunc('week', CAST(it.created AS timestamp)) as week
from items it
    left join users uu on uu.id = item.owner_id
group by uu.id, week
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your query:

- You have a `left join` from `items` to `users` as if you expect some items with no valid user id.
- You are using `u.id` in the `select`, but that would be `NULL` with no match.

I would suggest:

```
select it.owner_id,
       date_trunc('week', it.created::timestamp) as week_start,
       date_trunc('week', it.created::timestamp) + interval '6 day' as week_end,
       count(*) as this_week,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by uu.id order by min(timestamp)) as running_count
from items it
group by it.owner_id, week_start;
```

This uses Postgres syntax because your code looks like Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Remove user id from the GROUP BY clause and from SELECT list:

```
select
  count(*),
  date_trunc('week', CAST(it.created AS timestamp)) as week
from items it
  left join users uu on uu.id = item.owner_id
group by week
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a little runnable sample (SQL Server), maybe it will help:

```
create table #temp (week int, cnt int)

select * from #temp

insert into #temp select 1,2
insert into #temp select 1,1
insert into #temp select 2,3
insert into #temp select 3,3

select 
week, 
sum(count(*)) over (order by week) as runningCnt
from #temp
group by week
```

The output is:
week - runningCnt
1 - 3
2 - 5
3 - 6

So 1st week there were 3, next week there came 2 more, and last week one more.

You could also do a cumulative sum of the values in the cnt-column.